# how to get git for windows 10 running for a second user

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

I have installed git for windows as an administrator for the primary user and it works fine. Now I want to use it from another user account, but when I try to run git bash, it says that file has been deleted, remove shortcut? There's no sign of git from command prompt either.

I tried installing git as this alternate user, but it tries to overwrite the existing git that's installed from the primary user account. This is very frustrating. Is there any way to get git running for all the users on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed git for windows as an administrator for the primary user

No need to use a msi setup.
Simply unzip the archive (listed in [`git-for-windows/git/releases`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)) [`PortableGit-2.28.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.28.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.28.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, accessible by both accounts.
For instance: c:\git\2.28.0

Then make sure both accounts add to their PATH

```
set GH=C:\git\2.28.0
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

After that, `git`, `git-bash` or `bash -i --login` will be available for both accounts.

Comment: thanks! latest version for offline package: https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/git-for-windows/v2.28.0.windows.1/

Comment: @Marslo Thank you. I have updated the answer with more recent git version, from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Answer (score 0):

Installing GIT downloaded from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on Windows 10 should be straightforward :

- installing it should create a directory `C:\Program Files\Git` with everything you need to execute git-bash, whatever windows user is launching it.
- the system configuration is stored in a directory `C:\ProgramData\Git` which is accessible for all windows users
- The user configuration file is stored in the home directory of the user.
- So if you switch windows user, you should be able to launch it. Eventually you'd have to do a `git config --global --edit` to be able to set the username and email of the alternate account (and create the user config file).

I just verified with my own system:  I've installed the 2.9.0 version on windows10 and didn't change the default installation options. It works as expected using 2 windows accounts.

For the github desktop, the story is somewhat different:  github tries to install itself in the user's application data folders.  So every user will install its own one.

It's possible that the issue is related to to the installation of git-bash by github.  [Some issues](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/792) are registered for this installer.  In case of doubt, desinstall both applications, install git-bash from git-scm, then install github. Make a full transcript of your installation steps.  If it sill doesn't work, register an [issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues).